# Сообщения от Cron Daemon

Tags: cron, terminal, ос

Всем привет
С недавнего времени начал получать сообщения от Cron daemon в терминал.
Что это такое?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените картинку текстом. Добавте метку ОС.

Comment: перевод фразы «no such file or directory»: «нет такого файла или каталога».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Это понятно, я не понимаю откуда они лезут, лично я не устанавливал таймер на cron

Comment: отсюда: `$ sudo grep -rl aurorean /etc /usr /var`